# How to override GridView OnItemDataBound method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, overriding, controls

I want to create costume `Gridview`. I found very nice open source one but the problem is that it uses `DataGrid` and when I change the inherited class to `GridView`, I get the following error

> **AADGridView.OnItemDataBound(DataGridItemEventArgs
>   e):not suitable method found to override**

I have override here :

```
//public class AADGridView : DataGrid, IPostBackEventHandler
         public class AADGridView : GridView, IPostBackEventHandler
        {

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the auto filter is displayed in the AADGrid.AADGridControl.
            /// </summary>
            [Bindable(true), Category("Appearance"), Description("Whether to show the control's auto filter."), DefaultValue(true),]


            /// <summary>
            /// Override the DataGrid constructor.
            /// </summary>
            public AADGridView() : base()
            {
                // create the ArrayList to contain the DropDownList controls and the SortedList objects added to the header items;
                //list = new ArrayList();
                sort = new ArrayList();
                filter = true;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Override the OnItemDataBound event.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="e"></param>
            override protected void OnItemDataBound(DataGridItemEventArgs e)
            {
              //Some Code
               base.OnItemDataBound(e);
            }
```

as you see in the code, I just change `DataGrid` to `GridView`. Both of them has OnItemDataBound,So whats the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The event arguments are of type `DataGridItemEventArgs`. You have to change the parameter type to the new base class' parameter.

Comment: .How should i do that? please reffer me to some
@Sefe